# How to pass value from a second form back to first form in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, forms

I am relatively new to programming exclusively in c#. I usually use asp.net in the front-end and C# in the back end, but I am trying to learn how to do more with C#. Essentially, I have a form (form1) that has textboxes and a button on it to go to form2 (a configure form). On form2, I want to populate some textboxes from a database in SQL Server and also allow me to type in the textbox if needed to configure/change the value. Then, when hitting the accept button, I want to populate textboxes on form1 with the values that were in form2's textboxes.

So, what I need to basically know is 
<del>1) how do I populate textboxes using sql server</del>  
2) how do I then pass those values BACK to form 1? 

 
I have looked up/know how to pass typed in values from one form to another, but I am getting tripped up on getting them BACK to the first <del>form without using the pageload.</del>

**EDIT:** I am able to modify and save information that is being loaded from sql server, but when I go back to form 1, it does not reflect those changes. Here is my code:

**Form1:**

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Load the most recent configuration
            LoadConfig();
        }

private void LoadConfig()
    {
        // Populate the textboxes based on the last used settings
        // Create the SQL Connection
        String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        // Create the SELECT command
        String sqlSelect = //took out for formatting purposes, but its just a select from a table
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Set the textboxes to the values from the database
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    txtInstrumentNoType.Text = (read["instr_group_filter"].ToString());
                    txtDocType.Text = (read["doc_types_filter"].ToString());
                    txtPageThreshhold.Text = (read["pages_per_subfolder"].ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }


private void btnConfigure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open the Form2
            Form2 configureForm = new Form2();
            configureForm.Show();
        }
```

**FORM 2**

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the configuation
            ExecuteSqlUpdate();

        }


        private void ExecuteSqlUpdate()
        {
            // Create the SQL Connection
            String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

            // Create the UPDATE command to update the configuration settings
            // that are stored in the database
            String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Table" +
                                  "SET instr_group_filter = @instr_group_filter," +
                                  "    doc_types_filter = @doc_types_filter," +
                                  "    pages_per_subfolder = @pages_per_subfolder";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                // Replace the parameters with what is typed in the textboxes
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instr_group_filter", txtInstrumentNoType.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_types_filter", txtDocType.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pages_per_subfolder", txtPageThreshhold.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why do you need to avoid pageload? If you are on form2 then form1 is not longer current right? I would push those values to the database on form2 and on form1 pageload retrieve the values from the database.

Comment: @JacobH will send what I have in a few, currently reworking some of it

Comment: @seanLange The first forms textboxes are empty until I go into form 2 to retrieve the values or modify the values that I want to populate. I guess I should not have said without using pageload. If there is a simple way using pageload on form1, I am open for it.

Comment: You don't pass them back. You store them in the database on form2 when the user hits the submit button. After you save them you redirect to form1. On form1 you load the values from the database. On the initial load it wouldn't have any values yet so the form would be empty.

Comment: @JacobK I have added the code I have so far. Like I said, it will update the table like I need, but form1 does not reflect those changes

Comment: Define public controls or member variables in Form2, then read them from parent form.

Comment: @SeanLange I have added code to show what I have. It will update like I need, but form1 does not reflect the changes when going back to it.

Comment: When you say "going back to it" how are you getting there? Are hitting the back button in your browser? I don't see anything in Form2 that takes you to Form1. Maybe add a Response.Redirect("Form1")?

Comment: @SeanLange For some reason it was doing it itself. I may have had a this.close() somewhere else in the code. But looking into it, it does not recognize Response.Redirect when putting it after ExecuteSQLUpdate()

Comment: Are you using asp.net or winforms? Response.Redirect would be recognized in a web application which you stated you are using...looking at your code again now it looks like this is a winforms application??

Comment: @SeanLange yes it is a winforms application, no asp.net (unfortunately...). just dragging over controls to work on my c#

Comment: Sorry but I am not going to be much help. I haven't written a winforms application in over a decade. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) to show Form2. If the DialogResult is OK, then reload your configuration.

```
private void btnConfigure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open the Form2
    Form2 configureForm = new Form2();
    if (configureForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        LoadConfig();
    }
}
```

Before closing Form2, you should set the DialogResult accordingly.

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update the configuation
    ExecuteSqlUpdate();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close(); // Remove this line from your ExecuteSqlUpdate() method!
}
```

Using ShowDialog will cause Form2 to act as a Modal. It will block Form1 until Form2 is closed.

Comment: works like a charm. It is now able to update the tables on the configure webform, apply those changes to sql server, and go back to the previous form with the new values. Thank you so much!